# Probability density plot from ranked data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, probability-density

I have a ranked list of items (e.g. 1,, 1000), and after applying a given function, I can retrieve the relevant items to an input query (e.g. items in position 10, 14, 150, 263).

What I want to do is to plot the density function, that highlights the position of the retrieved items in the global list.

For example, It should compute the histogram of the retrieved items with different breaks, then draw the density.

Say, between 1 and 100 we have x items, between 101 and 200 we have y items .... .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you guys.

David

Comment: Does `hist()` not do what you want? E.g. `hist(sample(100, 20), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10))`? Otherwise, you should create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you need more specific advice.

Comment: Look into `geom_density()` within the package `ggplot2`.